# SqlDataAdapter.RowUpdated Event when update comes from another process

Tags: .net, database, wcf, client

Seems that the best way to detect a change in a datatable is to use the RowUpdated event from an SQLDataAdapter. But, what happens when I have 2 independent services and each one has its own set of clients and its own database connection?

If a database update is done from one of them, will the event fire in both independent services so I can inform all the clients that the data was updated?

BTW: The project is an IIS + WCF and Silverlight clients behind.

Answer (score 0):

The `DataTable` class has almost nothing to do with a database.  The `RowUpdated` event does not fire when there is a change to the database - it fires when there's a change to the (in-memory) `DataTable`.

In fact, the [`RowUpdated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.rowupdated.aspx) event does not detect changes in anything.

Comment: oops. And what can I do if I want to have 5 simulaneus connections in 5 WCF services and be able to know (in all 5 services) when a record is updated at any time?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175110%28v=sql.105%29